# Find all $n$ such that the following is prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, integers

Find all positive integers $n$ for which $(1+n+n^2+...+n^n)^2-n^n$ is prime.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). To avoid downvotes and closing you should add your own efforts to the question, and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: One such $n$ is 3, which gives the prime 997. Conjecture: this is the only one? There are no other solutions with $n\le 100,$ as I have checked with Mathematica.

Comment: Actually, there is another solution for $n=215.$ No further solutions with $n\le 1000.$

Comment: Are you sure that 215 works though? It would be way easier to just show that 3 is the only one

Comment: Probable... so you're not sure. Thus I guess evdntually 3 will be the only one... Why though?

Comment: Hold on... for n=3 the value of the expression is 1573=11*11*13 thus not prime... Are you sure you work on correct formula?

Comment: Ok I made the same mistake at first. Let's work on the proper one then ;)

Comment: @JonSmith With the help of Wolfram alpha, I found the expression which can be proven to be always composite (See answer below). Concerning the prime for $n=215$ (with the wrong formula). Since the number passed $300$ random bases in the Miller-Rabin-test, the doubt of the primality was only theoretical.

Answer (score 3):

Assume $n$ is a positive integer greater than $1$.

The sum $$1+n+n^2+\cdots n^n$$ is a geometric series with value $$\frac{n^{n+1}-1}{n-1}$$

Hence the number can also be expressed as $$\frac{(n^n-1)(n^{n+2}-1)}{(n-1)^2}$$ which is composite for every integer $n>1$

Comment: Checks out (+1). Too bad the question is kinda dismal. Unmotivated for starters.